# Scaling and Centering iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have this:

```
<div id="wrap">
   <iframe id="frame" src="https://www.webcamimageexample.com" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"  scrolling="no" align="centre">
   </iframe>                
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#frame {  
  -ms-zoom: 0.4;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(0.4);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

All works perfectly. However the alignment is off. I would like the image to move 50px to the right. I've tried to change the `-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;` but without any luck.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You made a typo around `align="centre"`, the correct value for this attribute is `center`.

Comment: Auto Correct. We like to use the queens english.. It is center

Comment: You talk about moving an "image"... What image? Do you mean the iframe?

Comment: Yes, the iframe is a still image from a webcam

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-transform-origin: top centre;
```

Worked and changed the Wrap size